# How can I lock a Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) desktop remotely (mobile, tablet)?

Tags: security

Often in a rush, I tend to forget to lock my desktop and rather than wait for the screensaver to kick in to lock the screen, is there a way I can use my mobile (Android, iPhone) or tablet (Android, iPad) to lock my desktop?

**EDIT**

Ideally the solution should be open source.

Comment: you arent going to find to many open source applications for iOS

Comment: do you want a free application ? or do you plan to play with the code of the application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program should suit your needs.

http://mobilepcmonitor.com/

Comment: Do you know of any open source solution?

Comment: As far as I can see they have free license for non-commercial use.

Comment: Add brief description of what to expect from the application so that others might find it usefull